# How to change tokens into trees (Python)

Tags: python, tree, token

I'm working on a python project which when you write in a line of an equation(including operators) it will calculate the equation for you.
First, if we write in a string, it would convert the string into individual tokens.

```
"12+2*3" -> [ "12", "+", "2", "*", "3" ]
```

Then, we would change each token into a tree.

```
[ "12", "+", "2", "*", "3" ]
```

-> [ ["12"], "+", [["2"], "*", ["3"]] ]

```
[ "(", "2", "+", "3", ")", "*", "7" ]
```

->
[[[["2"], "+", ["3"]], "(", []], "*", ["7"]]

Tokens must be grouped by a list in the order of operations, and if there are parantheses, it must be in the form of [[The number inside the parantheses], "(", []]

I am having trouble with the second part, coverting tokens into trees. It is recommended that I use a recursive function, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation you could use:

- Uses recursion
- Uses a dictionary to define the precedence of operators
- Has some basic error handling for when the expression is invalid (unbalanced parentheses, an unknown operator, ...)

```
def make_tree(lst):
    def report(op):
        op = f"'{op}'" if op else "end-of-input"
        raise ValueError(f"Unexpected {op}")
    
    def read_operand():
        token = next(it, "")
        if token == "(":
            expr, op = read_expression(0)
            if op != ")":
                report(op)
            return [expr, "(", []]
        elif token in precedence:
            report(token)
        return [token]
            
    def read_expression(level):
        left = read_operand()
        op = next(it, "")
        while precedence[op] > level:
            *left, op = [left, op, *read_expression(precedence[op])]
        return left, op

    precedence = {"(": 0, ")": 0, "": 1, "+": 2, "-": 2, "*": 3, "/": 3}
    it = iter(lst)
    expr, op = read_expression(1)
    if op != "":
        report(op)
    return expr
    
print(make_tree(["12","+","2","*","3"]))  # [['12'],'+',[['2'],'*',['3']]]
print(make_tree(["(","2","+","3",")","*","7"]))  # [[[['2'],'+',['3']],'(',[]],'*',['7']]
```